# JavaScript: Quadtree comparison

Tags: javascript, search, tree, difference, quadtree

I didn't find any fast algorithm for getting quad-trees differences in following format.
Let's say that we have two arbitrary 4 level trees:

[image]

```
var tree1 = [

    { id: "1.1", children: [

        { id: "1.1.1", children: null },
        { id: "1.1.2", children: null },
        { id: "1.1.3", children: [

            { id: "1.1.3.1", children: null },
            { id: "1.1.3.2", children: null },
            { id: "1.1.3.3", children: null },
            { id: "1.1.3.4", children: null }

        ] },
        { id: "1.1.4", children: null }

    ] },
    { id: "1.2", children: null },
    { id: "1.3", children: [

        { id: "1.3.1", children: [

            { id: "1.3.1.1", children: null },
            { id: "1.3.1.2", children: null },
            { id: "1.3.1.3", children: null },
            { id: "1.3.1.4", children: null }

        ] },
        { id: "1.3.2", children: null },
        { id: "1.3.3", children: null },
        { id: "1.3.4", children: null }

    ] },
    { id: "1.4", children: null }

];

var tree2 = [

  { id: "1.1", children: [

        { id: "1.1.1", children: null },
        { id: "1.1.2", children: null },
        { id: "1.1.3", children: null },
        { id: "1.1.4", children: [

            { id: "1.1.4.1", children: null },
            { id: "1.1.4.2", children: null },
            { id: "1.1.4.3", children: null },
            { id: "1.1.4.4", children: null }

        ] }

  ] },
  { id: "1.2", children: [

        { id: "1.2.1", children: null },
        { id: "1.2.2", children: null },
        { id: "1.2.3", children: [

            { id: "1.2.3.1", children: null },
            { id: "1.2.3.2", children: null },
            { id: "1.2.3.3", children: null },
            { id: "1.2.3.4", children: null }

        ] },
        { id: "1.2.1", children: null }

  ]},
  { id: "1.3", children: null },
  { id: "1.4", children: [

        { id: "1.4.1", children: [

            { id: "1.4.1.1", children: null },
            { id: "1.4.1.2", children: null },
            { id: "1.4.1.3", children: null },
            { id: "1.4.1.4", children: null }

        ] },
        { id: "1.4.2", children: null },
        { id: "1.4.3", children: null },
        { id: "1.4.1", children: null }

  ] }

];
```

So, I need to find differences and return them as:

[image]

```
var result = {

    "1.1.3.1" : "1.1.3",
    "1.1.3.2" : "1.1.3",
    "1.1.3.3" : "1.1.3",
    "1.1.3.4" : "1.1.3",
    "1.1.4" : ["1.1.4.1", "1.1.4.2", "1.1.4.3", "1.1.4.4"],
    "1.2" : ["1.2.1", "1.2.2". ["1.2.3.1", "1.2.3.2", "1.2.3.3", "1.2.3.4"], "1.2.4"],
    "1.3.1.1" : "1.3",
    "1.3.1.2" : "1.3",
    "1.3.1.3" : "1.3",
    "1.3.1.4" : "1.3",
    "1.3.2" : "1.3",
    "1.3.3" : "1.3",
    "1.3.4" : "1.3",
    "1.4" : [["1.4.1.1", "1.4.1.2", "1.4.1.3", "1.4.1.4"], "1.4.2", "1.4.3", "1.4.4"]

 };
```

If you can see, the result has to be a map or a dictionary corresponding to updates.
Didn't know how to reference ["1.1.3.1", "1.1.3.2", "1.1.3.3", "1.1.3.4"] to a single index, so I have split them, however if there is a more elegant way, you're welcome.

This data was created manually, so sorry if there're some mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a tree where you add a marker `where` for adding/deleting a part of the tree and get from this the difference.

```js
function getDifference(t1, t2) {

    function getD(object, parent) {
        function getKeys({ where, ...object }) {
            return Object.keys(object).flatMap(k => [k, ...(object[k] ? getKeys(object[k]) : [])]);
        }

        var types;

        Object
            .entries(object)
            .forEach(([k, { where, ...o }]) => {
                if (where) {
                    let keys = getKeys(o);
                    if (!types) types = {};
                    if (!types[where]) types[where] = [];
                    types[where].push(keys.length ? [k, keys] : k);
                } else {
                    getD(o, k);
                }
            });

        if (types) {
            if (-1 in types) result.push([types[-1], parent]);
            if (1 in types) result.push([parent, types[1]]);
        }
    }

    var temp = {},
        add = (inc, tree) => ({ id, children }) => {
            tree[id] = tree[id] || { where: 0 };
            tree[id].where += inc;
            if (children) children.forEach(add(inc, tree[id]));
        },
        result = [];

    t1.forEach(add(-1, temp));
    t2.forEach(add(1, temp));

    getD(temp);

    return result;
}    

var tree1 = [{ id: "1.1", children: [{ id: "1.1.1", children: null }, { id: "1.1.2", children: null }, { id: "1.1.3", children: [{ id: "1.1.3.1", children: null }, { id: "1.1.3.2", children: null }, { id: "1.1.3.3", children: null }, { id: "1.1.3.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.1.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.2", children: null }, { id: "1.3", children: [{ id: "1.3.1", children: [{ id: "1.3.1.1", children: null }, { id: "1.3.1.2", children: null }, { id: "1.3.1.3", children: null }, { id: "1.3.1.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.3.2", children: null }, { id: "1.3.3", children: null }, { id: "1.3.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.4", children: null }],
    tree2 = [{ id: "1.1", children: [{ id: "1.1.1", children: null }, { id: "1.1.2", children: null }, { id: "1.1.3", children: null }, { id: "1.1.4", children: [{ id: "1.1.4.1", children: null }, { id: "1.1.4.2", children: null }, { id: "1.1.4.3", children: null }, { id: "1.1.4.4", children: null }] }] }, { id: "1.2", children: [{ id: "1.2.1", children: null }, { id: "1.2.2", children: null }, { id: "1.2.3", children: [{ id: "1.2.3.1", children: null }, { id: "1.2.3.2", children: null }, { id: "1.2.3.3", children: null }, { id: "1.2.3.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.2.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.3", children: null }, { id: "1.4", children: [{ id: "1.4.1", children: [{ id: "1.4.1.1", children: null }, { id: "1.4.1.2", children: null }, { id: "1.4.1.3", children: null }, { id: "1.4.1.4", children: null }] }, { id: "1.4.2", children: null }, { id: "1.4.3", children: null }, { id: "1.4.4", children: null }] }],
    result = getDifference(tree1, tree2);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Don't know for now, cause I have 1D array of nodes and trying to figure out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196884/javascript-flat-one-dimensional-array-to-2d-tree] how turn them to 2D tree without much pain.

Comment: i have no idea of the new question. but what is with this answer?

Comment: I have convert 1D array into what I have here, however, pretty sure that your code would perfectly work.

Comment: Hm, can you tweak this function to get objects, not just their indices?
"1.1.3" to {id: "1.1.3", children: null }

Comment: do you want to get only the node with the change? the nested parts are included ...

Comment: Pardon, getting full objects as output could be a bad idea. Sorry for confusion. But I need to accompany indices with another key. 

Let's add another key to all objects {id: "1.1", info: "active node", children: [...] }

So, as output I need not just indices, but

[
  [
    [
      {id: "1.1.3.1", info: "active node" },
      {id: "1.1.3.2", info: "passive node" },
      {id: "1.1.3.3", info: "active node" },
      {id: "1.1.3.4", info: "active node" }
    ],
    "{id: 1.1.3", info: "passive node" }
  ],
...

Comment: maybe you ask a new question with the new objects and your wanted result.

Comment: It's a bad idea. Anyway thanks a lot. I will try it to do by myself.