# JavaScript Set value at multidimensional array where dimensions are not pre-defined

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, resize, extend

Let's say I have an empty 1D array:

var data = [];

Now, I want to add value of 1 to data[1][1][3];

To do this, I need to extend data array to:

```
data = [

 [],
 [],
 [[],[],[1]]

]
```

Yeah, pretty sure that I have to write a function and pass dimension values as 1D array [1, 1, 3] and check 1. if there is second, third dimension and if 'no' create them and 2. if its size are greater or equal.

For just this example, function would be

```
function setData(value_, index_){

  if(data[index_[0]] == undefined){

    data = Array(index_[0] + 1).fill([]);
    data[index_[0]] = Array(index_[1] + 1).fill(1);
    data[index_[0]][index_[1]] = Array(index_[2] + 1).fill([]);
    data[index_[0]][index_[1]][index_[2]] = value_;

  }else{

    if(data[index_[0]][index_[1]] == undefined){

      data[index_[0]][index_[1]] = Array(index_[2] + 1).fill([]);
      data[index_[0]][index_[1]][index_[2]] = value_;

    }

  }

}
```

It's clumsy and straight-forward. How I can make an universal thing out of it?
For any # of dimensions.

```js
var data = [];

setData(false, [1, 1, 3]);

function setData(value_, index_){

  if(data[index_[0]] == undefined){

    data = Array(index_[0] + 1).fill([]);
    data[index_[0]] = Array(index_[1] + 1).fill(1);
    data[index_[0]][index_[1]] = Array(index_[2] + 1).fill([]);
    data[index_[0]][index_[1]][index_[2]] = value_;

  }else{

    if(data[index_[0]][index_[1]] == undefined){

      data[index_[0]][index_[1]] = Array(index_[2] + 1).fill([]);
      data[index_[0]][index_[1]][index_[2]] = value_;

    }

  }

}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function might help you

```
var data = []

setData(false, [1, 1, 3])

function setData(value_, indexes_) {
  var currenLevelArr = data
  var len = indexes_.length
  // you can also use Foreach instead of  using for
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]] === undefined) {
      if (i === len - 1) {
        // we meet the target
        currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]] = value_
      } else {
        currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]] = []
        currenLevelArr = currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]]
      }
    } else if (Array.isArray(currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]])) {
      if (i === len - 1) {
        // we meet the target but
        //there is an extra dimension in the place
        //in which we want to set the value_
        console.error('something went wrong')
      } else {
        currenLevelArr = currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]]
      }
    } else {
      // the current position is filled with sth that we dont expect
      // if you want to replace the value ,you can add extra condition here
      console.error('something went wrong')
    }
  }
}

console.log(data)
```

this is the way you can trace the `nodes` object

```
var nodes = [

  {id: "1", x: 0, y: 0 },
  {id: "1.1", x: 0, y: 0 },
  {id: "1.1.1", x: 0, y: 0 },
  {id: "1.2", x: 1, y: 0 },
  {id: "1.3", x: 0, y: 1 },
  {id: "1.4", x: 1, y: 1 },
  {id: "1.3.1", x: 0, y: 0 },
  {id: "1.3.2", x: 0, y: 1 }

];

data = [];

nodes.forEach(function(node_){

var indices = node_.id.split(".");
indices = indices.map(function(d_){ return Number(d_) - 1; })
setData(true, indices);

});

function setData(value_, indexes_) {
  var currenLevelArr = data
  var len = indexes_.length
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]] === undefined) {
      currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]] = { value : undefined ,  subData : [] }
      if (i === len - 1) {
        currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]].value = value_ ;
      } else {
        currenLevelArr = currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]].subData;
      }
    } else  {
      if (i === len - 1) {
        currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]].value = 10 ;
      } else {
        currenLevelArr = currenLevelArr[indexes_[i]].subData
      }
    }
  }
}

function show(data , str="") {
  if(Array.isArray(data) ){
    for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++ ) {
      if(data[i]) {
        if(data[i].value) {
          console.log(str + (i+1) + ": true" );
        } 
        show(data[i].subData , str + (i+1) + ",")
      }
    }
  }
}
show(data)
console.log(data);
```

Comment: It doesn't work well with this data https://jsfiddle.net/leprous/219sybL3/ (

Comment: the data structure and the rules I think are different. could you please tell me what are `x,y` in `nodes`

Comment: I assumed every slot of array should be assigned once. I think for this `nodes` you should use objects

Comment: I'll write a new function base on `nodes` data structure

Comment: Why do you need to know x,y params? The ID is only one that involved, cause I'm splitting it to dimensions, i.e. 1.1.2 to [1, 1, 2].

Comment: You can use var nodes = [

  "1",
  "1.1",
  "1.1.1",
  "1.2",
  "1.3",
  "1.4",
  "1.3.1",
  "1.3.2"

];

It doesn't work as well. Forget about objects.

Comment: the reason is that we set the `data[0] = 'true'` then we want to set `d[0][0]` .it means that the d[0] have to be an array . we can keep only one value in `data[0]` . we need to use data structure like this `[{value,subArray:[]}]`